# New rules are not feeding from a partial .scss files into the main .css file

Tags: html, css, sass, blazor, partial

I have been working on this Blazor project for some time, and, until recently, all of the css from my partial .scss files has fed into my styles.css file. Now, when I edit any of my .scss files, the edits do not make it into the styles.css file.

Here is a selection form my Razor HTML (Note that the class is "gridBtn"):

```
@page "/TelerikGridSelect"

<h3>TelerikGridSelect</h3>

<div class="pageSize">
    <DxDataGrid Data="@GridData">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <DxToolbar>
                <DxToolbarItem Name="btnAdd"
                               Text="Add"
                               Tooltip="ToolTip"
                               CssClass="gridBtn" />
                <DxToolbarItem Name="btnAddFrom"
                               Text="Add From"
                               Tooltip="ToolTip!"
                               CssClass="gridBtn" />
            </DxToolbar>
        </HeaderTemplate>
    </DxDataGrid>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant part of _grids.scss (The variables are listed in _variables.scss and work everywhere else):

```
.gridBtn {
    color: $primary_text_color;
    background-color: $primary_color;
}
```

My styles.scss file contains `@import "grids";`, but styles.css does not have "gridBtn" anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you building your SCSS?  Is the output file being updated - datestamp?  The problem would appear to be in your SCSS compilation process but you provide no detail.  There's an article here on SASS with Blazor using the WebCompiler VS extension if it's any help - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5289921/Blazor-and-CSS-Frameworks.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun, the datestamps were 3/15/21 for styles.css, and 3/16/21 for styles.scss, so that's consistent with the problem being in the compilation process. I went into Koala, manually compiled styles.scss, and voila, the datestamps updated, and my problem is resolved. Thanks again!

Comment: I've added the last comment as the answer.  Can you please tick if off as accepted and the your question will be closed.  Tidies up the system so other helpers don't waste time looking at an answered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the output files and your SCSS compilation process to make sure your output files are being compiled.  Check the data stamps.